# A deceptive integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> $\int{\frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{x+6}}dx$

This looked pretty simple to me at first, but soon I realized the algebra behind it is so tedious, and online calculators show this same problem. 
I let $u=\sqrt{x-3}$, therefore $du=\cfrac{1}{2u}dx$, so $dx=2u \ du$

then \begin{align*}&\int{\frac{u}{u^2+9}}2u \ du \\ =& \ 2\int{\cfrac{u^2}{u^2+9}du} \\ \end{align*}

It is at this point I keep going in circles with substitution. I even tried multiplying by a conjugate to get a sum on the numerator so I could split the integral into two integrals, but did not go far with this. Is there a simpler or quicker way of solving this integral?

Comment: Hint: $\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} dx = \arctan (x)$.

Comment: Yes I see where that identity comes in this, especially in the last line. But I'm struggling with making that come to fruition

Comment: Long division of polynomials will fix your problem.

Comment: Hint: add and subtract $9$ in the numerator.

Comment: $\frac{u^{2}}{u^{2}+9}=1-\frac{9}{u^{2}+9}$ and then proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u^2=u^2+9-9$$

it becomes
$$2\int(1-\frac{9}{u^2+9})du=$$

$$2(u-9\int \frac{1}{9(v^2+1)}(3dv))=$$
$$2u-6\arctan(v)=2u-6\arctan(\frac{u}{3})+C$$